# Fetch data before CanActivation called

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating web application which uses REST to fetch data (Spring Boot application). The server uses cookies to authenticate logged user.

When user sign in, I save informations about him in service called `AuthenticationHolderService` (provided in `root`, because every component will need to share it). Every other route has `CanActivate` guard which don't let you get in if user informations in service equals `null/undentified`. Also in this service I have BehaviourSubject to notify when User sign in.

`CanActivate` uses `HttpClient` to obtain Observable which is returned when session was created, but website was reloaded (F5).

But still there is a problem. When you reload page, AuthGuard let you go in, because session is still created (Cookie that identifies session still exist) but, due to `ngOnInit` component method is called before Guard I am still getting wrong data.

I tried to put the API call to fetch logged user data in `ngOnInit` `AppComponent` method. Also, I tried to use resolvers (class that implements `Resolve<Any>` interface) to fetch user data, and instead of returning Observable in CanActivate, check if there is user in `AuthenticationHolderService`. Nothing worked.

When I subscribe sign in user notifier (`BehaviourSubject.next()` method), and when I reload page when session was created, I expect to update `AuthenticationHolderService` before ngOnInit component method.

Edit: I will explain it in other way (Because i though there was a different source of problem): When user sign in, I set property of `AuthenticationHolderService.signedUser`. I also have `AuthGuard` that let you enter to the component when you have `JSESSIONID` cookie, so when you reload page you won't be redirected to login page when you refresh (F5).  Also I implemented `OnInit` method in AppComponent, so if the `JSESSIONID` cookie is present, I will load user and set `AuthenticationHolderService.signedUser`. The execution order is like this: `AppComponent.onInit` -> `CanActivate`, but the method to fetch user data executes after `CanActivate`, so in `ngOnInit` guarded component you still don't have informations about signed user. I know that, I can use `Observables.pipe`, `tap` and `pipe` methods of rxjs, but if i do so, I will have to fetch data in `AppComponent.onInit` and 'CantActivate` (same informations twice)

Comment: I'm not sure what the real problem is here, maybe you can explain a bit more. Can't you subscribe to a subject in your AuthGuard to trigger when it is ready there? Or maybe you can try a other life cycle hook, like `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: I tried this in my application. Just for clarification: You want to get the data in the app.component? The only solution I see here is to add a Subject to your AuthGuard to which you subscribe in your App.Component to get triggered when it was called

Comment: I edited question. I need to sign user in 'AuthenticationHolderService.signedUser', but there might be case when you won't trigger `CanActivate` but you have to sign user in `AuthenticationHolderService.signedUser`, like when you want to load data to main page (which is accessible for everyone, so no `CanActivate` needed)

Comment: Do you use the HTTPInterceptor interface? If so, you can check this way whether a cookie exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sollution. The best way to fetch data before `CanActivate` is called, and don't dealing with asynchronous `CanActivate`, is to fetch data before application initilize. 
To achieve it, I created service, and used `providers` section and add `provide` as follow:

```
provide: APP_INITIALIZER, multi: true, useFactory: loggedUserProvider, deps: [LoggedUserProviderService]
```

What you have to know, is you can't inject any `providers` to create service (atleast you can't inject `HttpClient`). You have to inject `Injector`, and use it to get for example `HttpClient`

Answer (score 1):

First setup the Interceptor class, which can decide where to go.

```
@Injectable()
export class OAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private m_refreshRequest: Observable<HttpResponse<any>> | null = null;

  private getHeader(request) {
    if (this.tokenStore.HasUserToken === true) {
      return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.tokenStore.AccessToken
        }
      });
    }
    return request;
  }

  private refreshToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (this.m_refreshRequest === null) {
      console.log('[Interception] Request new Token');
      this.m_refreshRequest = this.userService.refresh();
    }

    return this.m_refreshRequest.pipe(flatMap(
      (result) => {
        this.m_refreshRequest = null;
        return this.sendRequest(this.getHeader(request), next);
      }
    ));
  }

  private sendRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      // Send the user to the login page If there are any 'Unauthorized' responses
      if (err.status !== 500) {
                this.failed();
            }
      return throwError(err);
    }));
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.indexOf('/oauth/v2/') !== -1) {
      console.log('[Interception] Token request');
      return this.sendRequest(request, next);
    }

    if (this.tokenStore.isExpired(120)) {
      console.log('[Interception] Token expired');
      if (this.tokenStore.HasUserToken) {
        return this.refreshToken(request, next);
      } else {
        this.failed();
      }
    }

    return this.sendRequest(this.getHeader(request), next);
  }

}
```

Then insert this in the provider section of your app.module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    ...
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: OAuthInterceptor, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With that mechanism you can also set your `AuthenticationHolderService.signedUser`to `true` somewhere in the Interceptor.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do use HttpInterceptor, but for XSRF purposes. I guess, this won't help since the `signedUser` isn't of type `boolean` but of type `User` and stores data like: firstName, lastName, userId and so on, which I need in `GuardedComponent.ngOnInit' method. I am not using OAuth, I am just using cookies to identify session.

Comment: What if `AuthenticationHolderService` does the request for userdata. With the Interceptor you always be sure not to do something with a missing cookie. Your App.Component could trigger the request for user data, stored in the `HolderService` that can then be used by your guarded component

Comment: `AppComponent` do it. And everything works fine until you refresh (F5) page. Then, its like `AppComponent.ngOnInit` is called, and call method to fetch `User` data, then `CanActivate` is called, but application still dont get response from server. The best way would be to implement `Resolver`, that is responsible to do it and set it on `AppComponent`. The other way would be to create an `Observable` that notify when `User` data is fetched and use it in `CanActivate`. What do you think about that?

Comment: I think these are two different things. The first one is the routing: Check, whether the route can be activated, is something that is not asynchronous, just look in the store for the cookie. The second one is the server request for user data, which can be started in any component. With the HttpInterceptor you can be safe to only fetch data if a valid cookie is available. Your userservice stores all the information and events should trigger the connected components. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: You are right. `UserService` stores data about user and notify can notify other components when the `User` data response comes. But, like i said earlier, there is still a problem, when `AppComponent.ngOnInit` calls method to fetch data from API, and when response comes set the value of property `AuthenticatiomHolderService.signenUser`, but reaponse comes after `CanActivate` let you get to guarded uri. That means, `GuardedComponent.ngOnInit` method is called before `User` data is received from server (which means `AuthenticationHolderService.signedUser` is null when `ngOnInit` is called)

Comment: What i want to achieve, Is force `CanActivate` to wait to trigger when fetching `User` data from server in `AppComponent.ngOnInit` response comes.